# How to combine values in table

Tags: sql, sqlite

The database has the schema students(name TEXT, score INTEGER), and there is a table called grades:

```
Grade   MIN_score    MAX_score
A       4            5
B       3            4
C       2            3
```

I want to select the names of all students and their grades according to the table, and turn A and B to 'pass' in the resulting table.

Below is my partial solution without turning A and B to 'pass' in the resulting table, and I wonder how to achieve that additional function.

```
SELECT name, grade
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN grades 
ON grade BETWEEN MIN_score and MAX_score;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `between`.  You'll get duplicates.

```
select s.name, s.score,
       (case when g.grade in ('A', 'B') then 'Pass' end) as status
from students s join
     grades g
     on s.score > g.MIN_score and s.score <= MAX_score;
```

You need to be very careful about the `join` condition so a score of "4" is not treated as both an "A" and a "B" (as `between` would do).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `case when` expression, e.g.:

```
select case when grade in ('A', 'B') then 'Pass' else '' end
```

I believe you query should be something like this:

```
select name, score, case when grade in ('A', 'B') then 'Pass' else '-' end
from students
join grades on score between MIN_score and MAX_score
```

Comment: How can I use it specifically?

Comment: Thanks. But how can I incorporate this into my query?

Comment: else ‘-’ is not what I want. 'else' should return the grade in that case (C in this example).  How should I achieve this?

Comment: You mean, return `C` in that case?

Comment: Yes. Can I replace else '-' by else grades.Grade?

Comment: Sure, simply use `else grade`